# TridionSites 9.6 and DXA 2.2 upgraded: PCA client returned an unexpected response when retrieving page model data for page

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, sites-9.6

We are getting the http 500 error on the webpage which are using the Redirect page templates. While trying to investigate we found that when DXA is trying to call the PCA client to get the page model, it throws the below error. Page preview works fine.

Update:
Solution - TBB references update to R2 was missing.

Comment: I see that someone made an edit (which I did not approve yet) with a solution. Please put the solution as an answer to this question, not as an edit.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer to your question, so others can see it was resolved

Comment: @user5629, Welcome to Tridion stack exchange, please also update your question about that error message.